# Expected Shortfall for ARMA-GARCH two day forecast

Tags: time-series, arima, garch, finance, risk

I need to find the 99% confidence expected shortfall (CVaR) for a long position of 100 dollars at time $t$ for an asset with returns modeled by an ARMA(1,1)-GARCH(1,1) model with $r_t = θr_{t−1} + u_t + ψu_{t−1}$,  $u_t = σ_t\epsilon_t$,  $σ^2_t = ω + αu^2_{t−1} + βσ^2_{t−1}$,where $\epsilon_t$ are independent and identically distributed standard normal random variables, and $θ,ψ,α,β$ satisfy conditions that make the market stationery.

This is a question from an old exam that was posted online by the department ([which you can see here](https://www.stonybrook.edu/commcms/ams/graduate/resources/201905QFpdf.pdf)) for students to study from to prepare for an upcoming exam, but no solutions were given and I have no idea how to begin finding the two-day expected shortfall for a time series analytically.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Edit: Expected shortfall or CVaR for confidence level $\alpha$ is the average value of the worst $1-\alpha$ percent of returns, given by $ES_\alpha(X) = \frac{1}{1 - \alpha} \int^1_\alpha VaR_u(X)du$ where the Value at Risk is given by $VaR_\alpha(X) = \{ Y|P(Y\leq X) = 1 - \alpha\}$.

Comment: Not a bad fit here, but another option would be posting this on Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange. For statisticians and machine learners here, you may wish to define expected shortfall mathematically.

Comment: Thank you! I will post there as well, and update the question to include the definition.

Comment: Actually, posting the same question on more than one site of the Stack Exchange network is discouraged. You should choose one.